# Having problems installing a GHCI in Debian 11 GNU/Linux

Tags: debian

I'm trying to install GHCI in Debian 11 GNU/Linux but the system won't allow me, It says that I'm not an admin.
If you post here some help I will surely could build a better question.

Thanks,
F.

Comment: so, as "not an admin" you don't have the privileges to install software. Can you *become* an admin? I'm assuming you're not asking this if you're on a system where the admin is a specific other person. Also, *how* did you try to install GHCI (whatever that is!)?

Comment: This computer is mine, I think that I might make a mistake when I was installing Debian 11. But I was quiet sure I was the admin. What might it happen if I format again the disk and began the installation progress for second time.

Comment: there's no reason to do that.

Comment: what happens if you do `sudo -s` ?

Comment: The same, feuergeist is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.

Comment: You might have locked yourself out of your system. No big deal, you can start any USB live Linux system, mount your root file system, and add your user to the group of users that can do sudo. If you've already have data/modifications on your debian, that is nondestructive, unlike your proposed complete erasure.

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Well, this is how I solve it. I install Debian 11 again. Perhaps when I have more time I could simulate the other option.

Comment: I finally install something called ghcut, the thing is that now I can't run the program as a regular user, only as su.

Comment: Is it impossible to post a screenshot in here?